# How to register mouse event on PNG file in Java?

Tags: java, png

So I have imported a simple image into my Python class. I also created a mouse listener and I'm trying to make it so that when you click on the picture, it registers a mouse event. Right now, I am creating a rect around where the image is and registering in that however, since my image is not a square (it's actually a dog) then it registers even when I am clicking on the empty part of the picture. How do I make it so that when I click on the empty part of the PNG it doesn't register but when I click on the picture part it does?

Comment: ".. since my image is not a square (it's actually a dog)" ... well no, PNG does not support dog-shaped images. It may be a square or a rectangle, but certainly nothing else. To determine if you clicked on the dog-part, you need to check if you clicked on a transparent pixel or not.

Comment: However, what if I had another object behind the PNG, like a background or something that's not transparent?